# replace a string, starting last occurrence of of a character

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

In this string:

`a=b&c=blablabla_[OO]`

I'm trying to replace everything between the "=" sign and the "[OO]"

I've tried:

`/(=.+?)_\[OO\]`

but this replaces starting the first "=" sign detected instead of the last (closest to [OO]).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of either 2 capturing groups or lookarounds combined with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^=]+` matching 1+ times any char except an equals sign:

```
(=)[^=]+(\[OO\])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4jfVIe/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups `$1REPLACEMENT$2`

---

With lookarounds (if supported)

```
(?<==)[^=]+(?=\[OO\])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mFXluE/1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching all the characters, don't match the = character, like this:

> /(=[^=]+?)_[OO]